# can't connect to MySQL database when using df.to_sql (pandas, pyodbc)

Tags: python, mysql, excel, pyodbc

I am trying to move information that is on several Excel spreadsheets into a single table on a SQL database. First I read the sheets using pandas and convert them into a single dataframe (this part works).

```
def condense(sheet):
    # read all excel files and convert to single pandas dataframe
    dfs = []
    for school in SCHOOLS:
        path = filePaths[school]
        try: opened = open(path, "rb")
        except: print("There was an error with the Excel file path.")
        dataframe = pd.read_excel(opened, sheetname=sheet)
        dfs.append(dataframe)
    return pd.concat(dfs)
```

Then I want to upload the dataframe to the database. I have read a lot of documentation but still don't really know where to begin. This is what I have currently.

```
connection = pyodbc.connect('''Driver={SQL Server};
                               Server=serverName;
                               Database=dbName;
                               Trusted_Connection=True''')
df.to_sql(tableName, connection)
```

I have also tried using an engine, but am confused at how to format the connection string, especially as I do not want to use a password. (What I tried below does use a password, and doesn't work.)

```
connection_string= 'mysql://username:password@localhost/dbName'
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
engine.connect()
df.to_sql(tableName, engine)
```

Any suggestions on how to create the engine without using a password, or where my code is wrong would be very appreciated.

Comment: Would really suggest using pymysql, it's much easier: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL

Comment: I just installed this. Should I use write_frame?

Comment: What you're looking is an ODBC setup. Look into Pyodbc. But do remember Pyodbc has unicode issues with MySQL.